# Google Calendar Event Creation send Notifications

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I was wondering if anyone knew how to notifiy attendees upon event creation in google calendar. When I create the event manualy, I can send an event as I wish. But when I create the event using the api with the javascript client library. I do not receive email notifications.

Here is my code for creation :

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
    'calendarId': '***@***.com',
    'resource': resource
});
request.execute(function() {
});
```

My resource variable is already defined and the event is added successfuly to the calendar, but no attendees receive any invitations. And if I go into the event on the calendar after creating it, the attendees are there.

Is there anything I am missing in the request to make it so that the attendees receive notifications upon the creation.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set parameter "sendNotifications" to true.
Here you can see that this is set to false at default.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Answer (score 4):

The attendees array has a responseStatus that you can set to:
"needsAction" - The attendee has not responded to the invitation.
"declined" - The attendee has declined the invitation.
"tentative" - The attendee has tentatively accepted the invitation.
"accepted" - The attendee has accepted the invitation.

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  'calendarId': '***@***.com',
  'resource': resource,
  'attendees': [{'email':'example@example.com','responseStatus':'needsAction'}]
  }
});
request.execute(function() {
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer J. A. Streich, thought the event responseStatus for attendees was already set to needsAction. Which is why I don't understand why the attendees are not receiving email. It says it needs action but don't send them an email.

Answer (score 2):

In the Java client there's the insert method of the event, and then there's the setSendNotifications method.
You'll have to do something like this:

```
Event createdEvent = calendario.events().insert("some-mail-from-google0@group.calendar.google.com", event).setSendNotifications(true).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

On the iOS version of the API, the sendNotifications property is on the request object - so you need to create the request first, then set the sendNotifications property before executing it. Look at the request object, see if the Java API is similar (likely).

e.g.
request.sendNotifications = true;

before calling
request.execute()

Answer (score 0):

Adding sendUpdates : 'all' in the parameter section will solve this issue.

I am using node js library googleapis, initially i have tried with the following code

```
const eventDetails = {
    summary: 'Meeting with ' + bookedProject.client_name,
    description: newMeeting.message,
    start: {
        dateTime: newMeeting.meeting_date,
    },
    end: {
        dateTime: moment.utc(newMeeting.meeting_date).add(15, 'minute'), 
    },
    sendUpdates : 'all',
    attendees: [{ email: bookedProject.client_email ,responseStatus:'needsAction'}],
};
```

But adding `sendUpdates : all` in options solved the problem like the below

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
google.options({
    params: {
        sendUpdates: 'all'
    }
});
```