# Send invites with google calendar API

Tags: java, spring, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a Java Spring API where I want to integrate Google Calendar.

The task:

- Basically creating an event for two attendees (users) and send them an invite with the option to accept/decline (standard GCalendar invite)

I tried this example here: 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java

But I think this is not the right one since I authenticate as a user - or do I need this to send them invites via email?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the notification to true.

> sendNotifications
>
> - Whether to send notifications about the creation of the new event. Optional. The default is False.

In the Try this API (Events: insert):

[image]

I'm not very familiar with java but try using this code as suggested in a related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25749735/5995040).

```
Event createdEvent = calendario.events().insert("some-mail-from-google0@group.calendar.google.com", event).setSendNotifications(true).execute();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

sendNotifications is depreciated.

You should use "sendUpdates" in de querystring, e.g. javascript:

```
    let request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
        "calendarId": workCalendar,
        "resource": newEvent,
        "sendUpdates": "externalOnly"
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `.setSendNotifications(true)` just before `execute()`.
this line is not there in google calendar example