# Google Calendar- Accept/Decline option

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have created an email and that is working perfectly fine. Now I want to add Calendar Invites inside my email. I never worked with calendars before. Can someone please suggest me what should I need if I want to add Google Calendar with accept and decline option? I want to keep my code very simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Base from my answer in the related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43222630/5995040). Try setting the notification to true.

```
// Refer to the Node.js quickstart on how to setup the environment:
// https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/node
// Change the scope to 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' and delete any
// stored credentials.

var event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'},
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': false,
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
    ],
  },
};

calendar.events.insert({
  auth: auth,
  calendarId: 'primary',
  sendNotifications: 'true',
  resource: event,
}, function(err, event) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
});
```

This will send notification to the attendee about the newly created event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this code but it didnot work. Any suggestions?